# Paper crumples or jams after laser printer fuser unit reassembly

Tags: laser-printer

Printer: Samsung Xpress M2070W monochrome laser printer

Fuser part number: JC91–01077A.

Problem: paper james when passing through some guide rollers that are meant to guide the paper out of the fuser unit and into the print out tray. 
[image: Samsung M2070W fuser unit]

Apart from replacing the fuser unit, what else can one do to fix the issue?

Comment: I agree it is a lengthy read but I considered it necessary to fully explain the problem I am facing and also to avoid questions such as "have you tried cleaning it with alcohol?" or "why don't you RMA it?" or what not.

Comment: Can you replace the rollers separately?

Comment: Well technically yes but where would I get them from?

Comment: You could try Samsung directly. A quick [google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=samsung+printer+parts) revealed these [two](https://www.samsungparts.com/ModelList.aspx?Catalog=Parts_and_Accessories&model=M2070W) [sites](http://www.partmaster.co.uk/) that may help you get the parts. We used to replace the rollers on Ricoh machines all the time.

Comment: I took it to a Samsung dealership and they said that the only way they could get a new pair of rollers is if they ordered a new fuser unit. Admittedly, I never thought of searching just for the rollers because I wasn't able to get a part number off of them, only the plastic material code is on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took the fuser unit apart again and removed the rollers altogether. After reassembly, it worked a charm except that the paper now has a slight bend to it (my guess is that as the paper passes through the fuser, it is bent around the fuser roller, heated up so that the plastic toner fuses to the paper and this causes the paper to remain slightly bent) but this really isn't an issue. Apparently, the rollers straighten the paper as it exits the fuser unit. I thought I should mention it if anyone else has this issue and decides to do the same.